# ASP MVC4 each post multiple comment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically, I would like to implement each post could post multiple comment features. However, when user comment on the first post, it didn't even submit the data to my controller so i cannot get the comment data, but if user comment on the second post, i can get the comment data. Why?

**My main view:**

```
{

            using (Html.BeginForm("ListPost", "Post", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "forms" }))
            {              
                    foreach (var item in Model.listPost)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PartialView/ListPost.cshtml", new PostModel(item))
                    }
            }

}
```

**My partial view:**

```
{

@model PostModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comment", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "forms" + Model.post.PostId }))
{    

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.post.PostId)

    @Model.post.PostMessage

    <br />

    @Html.Image(@Model.post.Member.Avatar.AvatarPath, null, "displayAvatar")

    <br />

    @Html.Timeago(@Model.post.PostedDate);

    <br />

    @Html.Label("Comment:")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.postComment.Message, new { @id = Model.post.PostId })

    <br />

    <input id= "@Model.post.PostId" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Post" />

}



}
```

Comment: This is creating invalid nested forms. Get rid of the outer form in the main view

Comment: Sir ~ You just save my life =D thanks you so much !!! I try to solve this error for few hour zzz

Answer (score 0):

Never render HTML form many times for comment(s) .

render a comment form once and move it to inside comment and use a hidden field which store the parent comment id. it will save a lot of resources to not render a form again and again on same page.

use JavaScript to move the form to child. I have done it in past and it run as expected.

Comment: There is no problem having a form for each comment, just so long as they are not nested